# Push Notifications not registering on App Store application - iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

We recently launched an update to an iPhone application. While our push notifications were working perfectly in ad-hoc, we've moved to live and they are no longer registering.

Looking at a live device log, we're seeing this:

**"Jun 11 09:40:05 unknown SpringBoard[5791] : No valid 'aps-environment' entitlement string found for application 'App Name': (null). Notifications will not be delivered."**

Now if you check on the internet or other stack-overflow conversations, there is a very common answer to this that the provisioning profile did not have "aps-environment" set as "production" correctly and the profile needs regenerating. However, this does not appear to be our issue as the binary clearly indicates it is in production aps environment. See details from the App Store Binary Details below:

[image: Screenshot from App Store Binary Details]

So we are a bit lost for what the problem could be. Given this information, as well as numerous checks I have done on my side, the profile and code signing appear to be correct and I can't find any other solutions to this online at the moment.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does the push notification uses the same port numbers for sandbox and production?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Looks like it was a server propagation issue and us testing thoroughly as soon as it was out the door.

I will post again in a few hours once we've fully had time to test and diagnose.

Comment: Note that 1: Blurring text is unreliable redaction, 2: "969S8T7MM9" uniquely identifies the company and possibly the app.

Comment: thanks, I know this and expected such comments, I just didn't want to make it dead easy for people.

If you want to go do the research, be my guest :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this problem worked itself out in the span of 3 hours; it must have been a server propagations issue.

**To anyone who might pull their hair out in the future on this one**: If your app JUST went live and the notifications aren't registering and you are certain that the aps-environment is set correctly, wait a few hours prior to concluding that the app has an issue.

Our app was launched in the Canadian iTunes Store only and the push notification registration issue resolved itself within a 3 hour period.

If anyone in the future can explain why this happens or add more detail to this, I'll gladly accept their answer.

Comment: i did not get u.. how u resolved this issue.... i have the same problem , did u modify any code or any settings?  please guide me  Thanks in advance  @spadict

Comment: No, it literally resolved itself. I was in the office pulling my hair out for about 3 hours trying to figure out what the problem was and then Push Notifications started working.

I can only assume this was a server propagation related thing on Apple's side that resolved itself. 

This is currently the accepted answer as a means of calming other developers who might be experiencing what I did. If you still have a problem after waiting a while, it could be something different.

Comment: I have the same issue. And the problem is that I haven't added a check while sending the notification ID to the server. So Apple tells me the app crashes at that point. I created an adhoc build and everything is working perfectly! Is there anything I can do to check why this is happening? I removed crashlytics as well before sending the IPA to Apple.

Comment: @Anil , unfortunately I don't think this is the same problem. My concern involved no crashes. There was simply a server propagation delay from all I could see.

Comment: @spadict mine started working properly after a few hours just like you said.